# Graphviz Python visualization execution error

Tags: python, graphviz

I installed graphviz in anaconda version 2.7, but while executing graphviz I find an error that says:

> InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add GraphViz to your PATH before you call it, as such:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

Of course be aware that the directory you've installed GraphViz in might differ from mine.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced a similar issue.
Install `graphviz msi`
and add variable path from system settings.
Restart your terminal it will solve the issue.